# Only local connections are allowed, Connection refused while running ChromeDriver through GitHub actions

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, github-actions, devops

I was trying to run selenium automation scripts through GitHub actions in Self-Hosted runners. my test execution is failing due to below error.

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (37******49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 44925
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Connection refused (localhost:44925)
```